# SecurityException when accessing SPFarm PropertyBag from WCF service hosted in SharePoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've hosted an WCF service in SharePoint 2010 (basicHttpBinding) using [this tutorial](http://www.sharepointbits.com/blog/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010.html). The assembly is deployed to the GAC and contains the WCF service and a timerjob. Both call the same method. The timerjob works successful.

But when I call the method of the WCF service, I get an exception, that it can't write a property in the SPFarm PropertyBag.

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Access denied.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Update()
   at MyCompany.MyProduct.Business.Config.SetPropertyValue(IPropertyBag propertyBag, String propertyName, String value)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

I tried to call the method using the Farm Administrator account and tried to use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges, but to no success.

I checked WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() inside and outside the elevated privileges block, outside it's the callers user and inside it's the **user of the WebApplications AppPool**.

So the AppPool user is correctly impersonated, but SharePoint 2010 "[disallows modification ... to all objects inheriting from SPPersistedObject in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace ... from content web applications](http://unclepaul84.blogspot.com/2010/06/sppersistedobject-xxxxxxxxxxx-could-not.html)"

The article says, there is a switch SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied (namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration) to get rid of this behaviour, **but I can't rely on administrators to use this to get my solution running**.

So I'm still without a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hack to work around the problem. I will not use it, because it is really dirty, but maybe somebody needs it, so:

1. Don't call the WCF Service by a normal web application URL. Use the URL of the Central Administration (e.g. http://myserver:9999/_vti_bin/project/myservice.svc)
2. Run the part where you change the Farm Properties with elevated privileges (`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`).
3. Before the elevated part (now it gets really dirty) set `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["FormDigestValidated"] = true;`

As I said, not a nice one, but working ...

Answer (score 0):

The security credentials from the calling process are probably copied. You can configure WCF whether or not to do this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx for more information.

Comment: As far as I can see, I can't change that, because I use the factory (http://www.sharepointbits.com/blog/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010.html) or maybe I misunderstood your answer ... can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Step 5 in your link talks about NTML credentials. This is probably the culprit. Couldn't you change this to not send any security credentials, just to test whether this makes a difference?

Comment: This won't work, because the service demands an NTLM authentication. If I don't send the credentials, the WCF service returns 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: I take it this specific method requires administrative privileges? Are you calling the WCF service from an account with administrative privileges?

Comment: I edited the question: I found, that SharePoint 2010 has a new feature that disallows WebApplications to access farm administration objects. So, the credentials are correct, but SharePoint blocks the access, because it comes from a WebApplication.